# Perfective aspect

Tags: grammar

> We love Thai food.

How do you consider it is Perfective aspect because this aspect shows complete and bounded action.

This sentence is not complete action.

What is a good definition of present simple aspect that can be understood?

Comment: Why do you think it's perfective? There are a number of different reasons for using the simple present tense.

Comment: @Stuart F, I don't think it's perfective as showing fact and continuous in present . Actually I don't understand what is perfective aspect in present tense!

Comment: "Perfective aspect in present tense" is a nonsensical but very official-sounding grammatical term that can be used to describe anything (like many other such terms). Online grammar advice is full of them. English has a Perfect construction (with _have_), but no perfective aspect per se. So don't worry about it. And the present tense is used for most stative predicates (including adjectives and nouns) -- _He's asleep, He's tall, She's a doctor, They own the house_ -- and in a generic sense with active predicates -- _He sleeps in that room, She rents the house,  That dog bites_.

Comment: If you travel and say I like spicy food, he loves silk, we enjoy music, everyone understands.  Not just in English, probably in most.

Answer (score 3):

English does not systematically distinguish perfective vs imperfective aspects in the way that (for example) Slavonic languages do.

For most verbs the "present simple" is used with a habitual or timeless sense, or in present-tense narrative. The so-called "present continuous" is used for a current state or activity.

For many verbs of perception and inner state, the "continuous" construction is not commonly used, and the "present simple" is used for both a present state and a habitual or timeless sense.

I don't think that perfective/imperfective is helpful in describing the use of these forms.